# Using one for loop how to iterate and test the iterator values?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, googletest

Here i need to use only one for loop(and no if condition inside) to test the iterator values using google test, Below is my code

```
TEST(EVTValSortedVector, StdIterator)
{
    int arr[3], i;
    int data = 4;
    arr[0] = int(2);
    arr[1] = int(1);
    arr[2] = int(3);

    EVTValSortedVector<int> eTerriers;

    EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers.isEmpty(), true);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        eTerriers.insert(arr[i]);
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers.isEmpty(), false);

    EVTValSortedVector<int>::iterator j = eTerriers.begin();
    EVTValSortedVector<int>::iterator k = eTerriers.begin();

    ++k;
    for (int i = 0; i < data - 1; i++, j++, ++k)
    {
        EXPECT_LE((*j), (*k));
        cout << "j and k value" << *j << *k << endl;
    }
}
```

> **Actual output:**
>
> j k
>   1 2
>   2 3
>   3 2
>
> **But i need output like this:**
>
> j k
>   1 1
>   1 2
>   1 3
>   2 2
>   2 3
>   3 3

If i get this needed output(above) then only my test cases will be passed.

Please help me to resolve this, my requirement is by using only one for loop and also no conditions checking inside the loop(no if condition).

Please help.

Comment: BTW, `EXPECT_TRUE` and `EXPECT_FALSE` is more adequate. And expected answers should be put on the left argument of `EXPECT_EQ`, not right.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to have only one loop, when you are trying to loop over more than one variable?

Comment: Its my task to do it using one loop using iterator functionality...

Comment: after inserting the sequence will be sorted order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *shouldn't* do this in one<sup>1</sup> loop.

```
for (auto i = eTerriers.begin(); i != eTerriers.end(); ++i)
{
    for (auto j = i; j != eTerriers.end(); ++j)
    {
        EXPECT_LE((*i), (*j));
        std::cout << "i and j value " << *i << *j << std::endl;
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup>: I include anything from `<algorithm>` that is at least linear in it's iterator arguments as a loop for the purposes of counting loops

If you have a less strict counting of loops, you can

```
#include <algorithm>

for (auto i = eTerriers.begin(); i != eTerriers.end(); ++i)
{
    std::for_each(i, eTerriers.end(), [i](auto & val)
    {
        EXPECT_LE((*i), (val));
        std::cout << "i and j value " << *i << val << std::endl;
    });
}
```

There is one way, but it's involves an `if` in the loop and is horrible.

```
constexpr std::size_t data = 3;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < (data * data); ++i)
{
    if ((i % data) <= (i / data))
    {
        EVTValSortedVector<int>::iterator j = eTerriers.begin() + (i % data);
        EVTValSortedVector<int>::iterator k = eTerriers.begin() + (i / data);
        EXPECT_LE((*j), (*k));
        cout << "j and k value" << *j << *k << endl;
    }
}
```

Rethink your requirements.